# Excel VBA Dictionary Data Integrity Issue

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I appear to have a significant data integrity issue using Dictionaries in Excel VBA which I use extensively in my code. I have a routine where I use a Dictionary to capture the best results from an optimization routine. Once captured, I then update an existing data table, using the results in calculations where a zero value will cause errors. This routine has been used extensively in the past with no errors. Therefore, I was surprised when errors started occurring. I tracked the error to what appears to be a Dictionary's data being corrupted outside of the actual code.

The Dictionary with the error is loaded by another Dictionary that continually looks for updates and only keeps the values that are better than previous ones, thus the optimization. Once these values have been captured, the Dictionary (DataItems) that causes the error loads the new values into a data table a variable at a time. Here is the code I used to trap the error:

```
If KeyCount <> DataItems.Count Then: Stop
NewValue = DataItems(NewData)
If KeyCount <> DataItems.Count Then: Stop
```

I captured the count of Items in DataItems prior to reading the data into the NewValue variable. Prior to reading the data the Dictionary had a count of 1, but after reading the data, the count went to 2. The original key became the key of a new record with an item value of zero and the original item obtained a new key that appears to be a value in the original bulk data being scanned. This appears to occur almost always with only one record in the DataItems dictionary.

I can use the same routine with other calling applications with absolutely no problems, so the problem appears to be tied to the calling application which makes no sense since the dictionaries being used originated in the routine where the error occurs. I have tried eliminating potential timing issues by stepping through the code and other debugging actions, but I remain extremely puzzled. It really makes me question the potential data integrity of using Dictionaries in Excel for application critical data. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. How are you populating the dictionary? What's in the `Keys` and `Values` arrays, vs. what is expected? What do "error" and "corrupted" actually stand for? Do you have many other conditional statements that use a superfluous (and easily confusing /bug-inducing) instructions separator like that?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you're using the Watch window and/or the Immediate pane while debugging, and that's what's causing the problem (or at least making it worse)... If you add specific expressions such as `DataItems("keyHere")` to the Watch list then when code is paused that watch will actually add that key if it doesn't exist.

Similarly, if when paused you do something like `? DataItems("thisKeyDoesNotExist")` in the Immediate window, you will not see any output, but *that key will silently get created.*

To illustrate:

```
Sub DictWatch()

    Dim d As Object, k

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    d.Add "one", 1
    Stop 'add a watch on the expression d("one") before proceeding
    d.RemoveAll

    Stop  'enter "? d("test")" in Immediate pane and hit enter before proceeding

    For Each k In d.keys
        Debug.Print k  'output is "one" and "test"
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: I did not know this +. Wonder why this is permitted?

Comment: It's just a "gotcha" to look out for - probably doesn't impact many people but can be frustrating...